# Using web content for Chromecast remote display

Tags: javascript, android, chromecast

When implementing [Cast Remote Display](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/07/cast-remote-display-api-processing.html) is it possible to show WebGL content on the remote screen (e.g. via a webview), which controlling that content with the phone?

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you post your code and if possible the error message that you are encountering

Comment: No code yet. Just wondering if it's possible in theory.